# Insert DataTable into table in StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, datatable

Here's how my `DataTable` looks like(2 columns: `Name` and `Code`):

**`Name     Code`**

```
name1 code1
name2 code2
name3 code3
```

I want to insert that `DataTable` into an existing table named `MyTable` that has a primary key and those 2 columns.

I really don't know how I should start coding my Stored Procedure, Is there any way to send as parameter a `DataTable` or something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: What DMBS are you using? And what version?

Comment: @GarethD I'm using sqlserver 2008

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx

Comment: Where is your core problem? Do you know how to create a sp that takes parameters and inserts a new record? If so, just use a `DataAdapter` and create it's `InsertCommand` with `CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure` and the appropriate parameters. Then it's simple as `DataAdapter.Update(DataTable)`.  ( or use table-valued-parameters as GarethD has mentioned, [**here**](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)'s a helful link )

Comment: PinnyM showed up a _very good answer_ by using the [SqlBulkCopy-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx) there is even a pretty good example code on the posted link!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz: Although `SqlBulkCopy` provides a very efficient way to bulk copy data into sql-server, it is not what OP has asked for. He wants to use a stored-procedure to insert records in a `DataTable`. `SqlBulkCopy` has it's drawbacks.

Comment: IMO idish asked for a solution to insert a complete dataTable into a database table with a storedProcedure. Is it considered as bad style or, even, unpolite (of course this is not my intention!) to throw in a comment which refers to another possible solution?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz It's totally OK for me, I like to see new techniques, anyways, I'll check the solutions later on, thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL-Server 2008 you can use [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). Something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTableType AS TABLE 
(   Name    VARCHAR(5),
    Code    VARCHAR(5)
);
GO;
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure (@MyTableType dbo.MyTableType READONLY)
AS
    INSERT dbo.MyTable (Name, Code)
    SELECT Name, Code
    FROM    @MyTableType;

GO;
```

Then simply pass your datatable as the value for a parameter (SqlDbType.Structured) in a SqlCommand.

Or you can use SQLBulkInsert and bypass the stored procedure.

Comment: And here's a link that might be helpful: http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/